# Generics in SCALA

Tags: scala, generics

I have a simple generic class in SCALA:

```
class Point[T : Numeric](val x:T, val y:T) {
  def + (other : Point[T]) : Point[T] = new Point[T] ( x + other.x, y + other.y)
  def - (other : Point[T]) : Point[T] = new Point[T] ( this.x - other.x, this.y - other.y)
  def unary_ : Point[T] = new Point[T](-this.x, -this.y)
  def == (other : Point[T]) : Boolean = (this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y)
  def != (other : Point[T]) : Boolean = !(this == other)
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Error:(4, 66) type mismatch;
 found   : T
 required: String
  def + (other : Point[T]) : Point[T] = new Point[T] ( x + other.x, y + other.y)
                                                                 ^
```

what is wrong with my generic?

Thank you!

Comment: Where does the `+` come from on `T`?

Comment: T can be only Int or Float, but I thought compiler will analyze generics the same way like C++ templates...

Comment: I don't know C++, but I do know what you haven't bounded `T`.

Comment: you mean Point[T <: AnyVal] ?

Comment: Well, yes. But `AnyVal` doesn't have a `+` method either. You need to bound `T` to a type that does have a `+` method. You could also use a structural type - but last I read they're slow.

Comment: Thank you! Got it. Now I trying to use [T : Numeric]. As I understand numeric has operator +. But anyway I have the same error...

Comment: i.e. even with T:Numeric it tries to specialize it with a String

Comment: I dont think Numeric has a + operator. (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric , https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/math/Numeric.scala#L1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was solved like this:

```
class Point[T : Numeric](val x:T, val y:T) {
  def + (other : Point[T]) : Point[T]  = new Point[T] ( plus(this.x, other.x), plus(this.y, other.y))
  def - (other : Point[T]) : Point[T] = new Point[T] ( minus(this.x, other.x), minus(this.y, other.y))
  def unary_- : Point[T] = new Point[T](negate(this.x), negate(this.y))

  def == (other : Point[T]) : Boolean = (this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y)
  def != (other : Point[T]) : Boolean = !(this == other)

  private val numeric = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  private def plus(x: T, y: T) = numeric plus (x, y)
  private def minus(x: T, y: T) = numeric minus (x, y)
  private def negate(x: T) = numeric negate (x)
}
```

So, I just use Numeric interface implicitly...
Let's make it even simpler:

```
import scala.math.Fractional
class Point[T](val x: T, val y: T)(implicit num: Fractional[T]) {
  import num.mkNumericOps

  def +(that: Point[T]) = new Point(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y)
  def -(that: Point[T]) = new Point(this.x - that.y, this.y - that.y)

  def == (other : Point[T]) : Boolean = (this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y)
  def != (other : Point[T]) : Boolean = !(this == other)

  def unary_- : Point[T] = new Point[T](-this.x, -this.y)
}
```

Comment: You may want to declare a private instance member to reduce boilerplate: `val numeric = implicitly[Numeric[T]]`